# Tensorflow 2.0 keras fit overrides the "training" parameter in call function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When creating a model using tensorflow 2.0 I am getting two different behaviours depending on how I do a forward pass:

1) If I do the forward pass using model(X) then it is fine and the "training" parameter in the call method works normally

vs.

2) If I use model.fit(X, y) to run the model instead then the "training" parameter seems to get overriden and set to None regardless of whether its default is True or False.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It means for example that I can't set up the model so that dropout only occurs when training is set to True.

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model

X = np.random.random((250, 5))
y = X[:, 0] > 0 * 1.0

class MyModel(Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)

  def call(self, inputs, training=True):
    print("Training ", training)
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    if training:
      x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
    return self.dense2(x)

model = MyModel()
```

Then this prints out **Training True** as expected:

```
model(X)    # prints out: Training True
```

But this prints out **Training None** ?

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')        
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1)   # prints out: Training None
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug:

> The training value of tf.keras.Model.call() becomes None when
>   tf.keras.Model.fit(). (tf2.0.0-alpha0)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27275

Answer (score -1):

This was resolved in newly released TF2.0.

Please replace `!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0` with `!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3` in the above code. Please check the [gist here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jvishnuvardhan/dd865ad9e3ae25be10fa6915de111c0e/untitled.ipynb). Thanks!

The output is shown below.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')        
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1)   # prints out: Training None

Training  True
Training  True
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6448
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f1f5961edd8>
```